# Chrome Extension Install with master_preferences Business

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to install a chrome extension behind the scenes and have it run. I notices that when I set my user profile to a new user or profile directory to a new location it creates a fresh profile with 4 common extensions, I need to update the "master_prefernece" file with my chrome extension info. Anyone have any luck with this? I am setting up a corporate environment and need a pre installed chrome ext to be on all.

Answer (score 0):

You may check possible [deployment options](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html) for Chrome.